# Using Provider in a Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new to Flutter/Firebase and am having an issue with Provider implenetation for a very simple CRUD contacts app. I'm not sure how to fix this.

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 284 pos 7: 'T != dynamic': Tried to call Provider.of. This is likely a mistake and is therefore
unsupported.
If you want to expose a variable that can be anything, consider changing
`dynamic` to `Object` instead.

Here's the code for the page where the save is done.

```
actions: [
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.done,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              //save data to firebase
              final uid = await Provider.of<dynamic>(context, listen: false)
                  .auth
                  .getCurrentUID();

              await db
                  .collection("userData")
                  .doc(uid)
                  .collection('contacts')
                  .add(
                {
                  'Name': widget.contact.name,
                  'PhoneNumber': widget.contact.phoneNumber,
                  'Location': widget.contact.location,
                  'Notes': widget.contact.notes
                },
              );
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory.

You need to use the correct type (or [Object](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-core/Object-class.html)) in the Provider.of statement instead of dynamic.

```
await Provider.of<CorrectType>(context, listen: false)
  .auth
  .getCurrentUID();
```

Comment: Okay I tried that - I'm now getting 'the getter 'auth' isn't defined for type Object

Comment: If you know the type then it's better to use that. In the case of Object you've to cast it using `as`.

`Object a = 1; var b = 2 + a as int;`

Comment: How do I know what type it is? This is my models file: 
`class Contact extends ChangeNotifier {
  String name;
  String location;
  int phoneNumber;
  String notes;`

  `Contact(this.name, this.phoneNumber, this.location, this.notes);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'Name': name,
        'PhoneNumber': phoneNumber,
        'Location': location,
        'Notes': notes
      };
 notifyListeners();
}
`

Comment: This class doesn't have `auth` field which you're trying to use.

Comment: happy to help you